# "imwrite" function not found

Tags: error-handling, 3d, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

My Google Colab says "error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:783: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'"
Here's the code:
#@title STEP2: Testing on web images
#@markdown * Find an image on the web
#@markdown * Right click and copy image address
#@markdown * Paste the image address to image_url
image_url = 'https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/821-8213704_rick-astley-transparent.png' #@param         {type:"string"}
path = '/content/pifuhd/sample_images/webImg'

```
#empty the folder
!rm -rf '/content/pifuhd/sample_images'
!mkdir '/content/pifuhd/sample_images'

!wget '$image_url' -O '$path'
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(path)
cv2.imwrite('/content/pifuhd/sample_images/webImg.png', img)
!rm -f '$path' 

import os
image_path = '/content/pifuhd/sample_images/webImg.png'
image_dir = os.path.dirname(image_path)
file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(image_path))[0]

# output pathes
obj_path = '/content/pifuhd/results/pifuhd_final/recon/result_%s_256.obj' % file_name
out_img_path = '/content/pifuhd/results/pifuhd_final/recon/result_%s_256.png' % file_name
video_path = '/content/pifuhd/results/pifuhd_final/recon/result_%s_256.mp4' % file_name
video_display_path = '/content/pifuhd/results/pifuhd_final/result_%s_256_display.mp4' % file_name

#preprosessing
%cd /content/lightweight-human-pose-estimation.pytorch/

net = PoseEstimationWithMobileNet()
checkpoint = torch.load('checkpoint_iter_370000.pth', map_location='cpu')
load_state(net, checkpoint)
get_rect(net.cuda(), [image_path], 512)


#run
%cd /content/pifuhd/
# Warning: all images with the corresponding rectangle files under -i will be processed. 
!python -m apps.simple_test -r 256 --use_rect -i $image_dir
# seems that 256 is the maximum resolution that can fit into Google Colab. 
# If you want to reconstruct a higher-resolution mesh, please try with your own machine. 

#clear everything
clear_output()
#render video
from lib.colab_util import generate_video_from_obj, set_renderer, video

renderer = set_renderer()
generate_video_from_obj(obj_path, out_img_path, video_path, renderer)

# we cannot play a mp4 video generated by cv2
!ffmpeg -i $video_path -vcodec libx264 $video_display_path -y -loglevel quiet
video(video_display_path)
```

I was expecting for the code to generate a 3D model from an image.